# Walk-Forward-optimization and Multilinear Regression: UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples

Tags: python, time-series, linear-regression, prediction

*[Here is the link to my onedrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Arkw7Y7i28Jikyvvs4Z9Ec5rdccR?e=NNaty5), where you can download dataset(.csv) and the python script.*

I am trying to predict electricity consumption (ec) using 5 different features (gdp, pop, exp, sp_500, temp). For that, I first perform a Walk-Forward-optimization as suggested [here](https://medium.com/eatpredlove/time-series-cross-validation-a-walk-forward-approach-in-python-8534dd1db51a) i.e. I take 350 of my observations (months) for the initial training and try to predict the next 6 months (351,352,353,354,353,356). In each iteration, I add 1 month such that the next training set has 351 months and predicts 352,353 usw.

```
#  initial: initial train length 
#  horizon: forecast horizon (test set length). Default = 1
#  period:  length of train data to add each iteration 

class expanding_window(object):
    
    def __init__(self,initial=1, horizon=1, period=1):
        self.initial = initial
        self.horizon = horizon
        self.period = period
        
    def split(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.counter = 0 
        
        data_length = data.shape[0]
        data_index = list(np.arange(data_length))
        
        output_train = []
        output_test = []
        
        # append initial
        output_train.append(list(np.arange(self.initial)))
        progress = [x for x in data_index if x not in list(np.arange(self.initial))]
        output_test.append([x for x in data_index if x not in output_train[self.counter]][:self.horizon])
        
        while len(progress) !=0:
            temp = progress[:self.period]
            to_add = output_train[self.counter] + temp
            
            # update the train index
            output_train.append(to_add)
            
            # increment counter
            self.counter +=1
            
            # update test index
            to_add_test = [x for x in data_index if x not in output_train[self.counter]][:self.horizon]
            output_test.append(to_add_test)
            
            # update progress
            progress = [x for x in data_index if x not in output_train[self.counter]]
        
        # clip last element of output_train and output_test
        output_train = output_train[:-1]
        output_test = output_test[:-1]
        
        # mimic sklearn output
        index_output = [(train,test) for train,test in zip(output_train, output_test)]
        
        return index_output

# Separate the predictors and label
X = data[data.columns[~data.columns.isin(
    ["gdp", "pop", "exp", "sp_500", "temp"])]]
y = data["ec"]

tscv = expanding_window(initial=350, horizon = 6, period = 1)
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    print("Train:",train_index)
    print("Test :",test_index)

for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(tscv.split(data)):
    print("Split",i)
    print("Train:",data[["gdp","pop","exp","sp_500","temp"]].iloc[train_index])
```

Subsequently, I try to fit a MLR model on the data, but I get this "UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples" and I receive an average Out-of-sample score less than 0 (-0.52).

```
# Multiple Linear Regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

ols = LinearRegression()
oos_score_list = []

print("Split  In-sample R^2  Out-of-Sample R^2")
print("-"*40)

# Loop through the splits. Run a Linear Regression for each split.
for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(tscv.split(data)):
    X_train = data[["gdp", "pop", "exp", "sp_500", "temp"]].iloc[train_index]
    y_train = data[["ec"]].iloc[train_index]
    X_test = data[["gdp", "pop", "exp", "sp_500", "temp"]].iloc[test_index]
    y_test = data[["ec"]].iloc[test_index]
    ols.fit(X_train,y_train)
    oos_score = ols.score(X_test,y_test)
    print(i,
          " "*4,
          round(ols.score(X_train,y_train),2),
          " "*10, 
          round(oos_score,2))
    oos_score_list.append(oos_score)

oos_score_list = oos_score_list[ : -1]
print("-"*40)
print("Average out-of-sample score:",round(np.mean(oos_score_list),2))
```

I know this means that I must have done something wrong in the modelling process, but I don't know what. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: At iteration `155` (the last one), your `test_index` is a list with only one value `[505]`. The warning says `UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples.`. Meaning that you would need at least 2 samples to have a "well-defined R^2 score", which is not the case for the last iteration of your `for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(tscv.split(data))` loop.

Comment: @guin0x thank you, that makes sense! Do you also have an idea, why I get a negative R^2 ?

Comment: [Your model fits the data poorly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative)

Comment: @guin0x is that inherent to the features I have chosen or is it sth in the code/model that I can fix?

Comment: I can't tell if its something inherent to the features. The code seems fine to me. Maybe it's a good idea for you to read Chapter 3 of the [ISLR](https://www.statlearning.com/) book? It will teach you a bit how to choose your Predictors properly. It is always a good idea to plot your data first, before start with regressions so you can analyse which features should be kept, if there are any interactions between them and/or if you should maybe fit a polynomial of a higher degree.